# sequence power series simplification

Tags: combinatorics, power-series

Let $\{a_n\}$ be the sequence

$a_n=\sqrt5\left(\frac{3+\sqrt5}2\right)^n - \sqrt5\left(\frac{3-\sqrt5}2\right)^n$

for each $n\ge 0$. Determine a rational expression for C(x) = $\sum_{n\ge0}a_nx^n$

completely lost here. should i split it up and use sum lemma or...? not sure how to deal with the ^n parts

Comment: You can develop the expressions $(3 +/- \sqrt{5})^n$ with its binomial expansion. Doing so, your series $\sum_{n} a_n x^n$ is a double sum that you can exchange. Then, it simplifies well. I obtained something like $\frac{x}{(1-x/2)(1-45x^2/4)}$ at the end, up to some constants and calculation mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2},b=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ Then, $a_n=(a-b)(a^n-b^n)$. Thus, $$\sum_{n\ge 0}a_n x^n=(a-b)\sum_{n\ge 0}(ax)^n-(a-b)\sum_{n\ge 0}(bx)^n\\=(a-b)\left(\frac{1}{1-ax}-\frac{1}{1-bx}\right)\\=\frac{(a-b)^2x}{1-(a+b)x+abx^2}=\frac{5x}{1-3x+x^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

By the geometric summation formula,
$$\sum_{n\ge0}r^nx^n=\sum_{n\ge0}(rx)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-(rx)^{n+1}}{1-rx}=\frac1{1-rx}$$
when you are in the radius of convergence.

This should get you started.